# Maps with Hopf invariant zero are suspensions

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $h:\pi_{2n-1}(S^n) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ be the Hopf invariant.  I believe that in the same paper that proves his suspension theorem, Freudenthal proved that if $x \in \pi_{2n-1}(S^n)$ satisfies $h(x)=0$, then $x$ is in the image of the suspension map $\pi_{2n-2}(S^{n-1}) \rightarrow \pi_{2n-1}(S^n)$.  Observe that the usual Freudenthal suspension theorem says that the map $\pi_{2n-1}(S^n) \rightarrow \pi_{2n}(S^{n+1})$ is a surjection.

Can anyone either describe a proof of this or point me in the direction of a modern source for it?  The only one I know of is Pontryagin's book "Smooth manifolds and their applications in homotopy theory", where this is Theorem 16, but I find his proof very hard to follow.  I guess I would particularly appreciate a proof in the spirit of Pontryagin's proof, though more algebraic proofs are welcome too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my notes "Homotopy groups of spheres and low-dimensional topology" (available on my page of notes [here](http://www.nd.edu/~andyp/notes/)), I have written up a modern account of Pontryagin's approach to calculating the homotopy groups of spheres.  In particular, Section 9 contains a detailed account of Pontryagin's proof of the theorem of Freudenthal you ask about.

Answer (score 8):

The integral statement is most generally this:

For a based CW space $X$ one has a suspension map $E: X\to \Omega \Sigma X$ and
a Hopf invariant $H: \Omega \Sigma X \to \Omega \Sigma (X\wedge X)$ (construction outlined below).

The composite
$H\circ E$ is canonically null and the sequence
$$
X \overset E \to \Omega \Sigma X \overset H \to  \Omega \Sigma (X \wedge X)
$$
is a homotopy fiber sequence in a range, roughly $3r$, where $r$ is the  connectivity of $X$.
Your result will follow from this easily (take $X = S^n$).

The map $H$ is often constructed as follows: let $JX$ be the reduced free monoid on the points of $X$. Using say the Moore loops model for $\Omega \Sigma X$, one can construct a monoid homomorphism $JX \to \Omega \Sigma X$ that extends the map $E$ using the universal property of the free monoid. A homology calculation shows that this map his a weak equivalence (James did this calculation when $X$ is a sphere).

Finally, the proof the above sequence is a fibration in the range roughly thrice the connectivity of $X$ can be deduced from the following four facts:

1) $J_2 X \to JX$ is $(3r+2)$-connected, where $J_2X = X \cup (X \times X)$ is filtration two.

2) The quotient $J_2X/X$ is $X\wedge X$, so we have a cofiber sequence
$$
X \to J_2 X \overset q\to X \wedge X
$$

3) By the Blakers-Massey Theorem, the above sequence is a homotopy fibration in
the range roughly $3r$.

4) The diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
J_2X@>q>>X\wedge X\\
@VVV @VVV\\
JX@>>H>\Omega\Sigma(X\wedge X)
\end{CD}
$$
is commutative, where the left vertical maps is the inclusion and the right one is the suspension map for $X\wedge X$.

Answer (score 4):

There is a $2$-local fiber sequence

$$S^n \to \Omega S^{n+1} \to \Omega S^{2n+1}$$

where the first map is the suspension map. Its associated long exact sequence of homotopy groups is called the *EHP sequence* and the induced map $\pi_{2n} \Omega S^{n+1} \to \pi_{2n} \Omega S^{2n+1}$ coincides with the Hopf invariant $\pi_{2n+1} S^{n+1} \to \mathbb{Z}$. This answers your question and yields a lot more information about homotopy groups of spheres.

Good modern references are Hatcher's *Spectral Sequences in Algebraic Topology* and Neisendorfer's *Algebraic Methods in Unstable Homotopy Thoery*. There are also versions of the EHP sequence at odd primes but they are more subtle, they are discussed in Ravenel's *Complex Cobordism and Stable Homotopy Groups of Spheres*.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  The statement I gave is not $2$-local.  What am I missing?

Comment: I guess you are not missing anything. This answers your question $2$-locally and integrally for odd $n$ since then the sequence above is also a fiber sequence without localization, but I have to admit I don't know the full answer. Sorry for the confusion, I should have made it clearer.

Comment: @Lisa: Just to add to Karol's answer. $S^n\rightarrow \Omega S^{n+1}\rightarrow \Omega S^{2n+1}$ is a fiber sequence (without localization) if $n$ is even. The fact that $\pi_{2n}\Omega S^{n+1}\rightarrow \pi_{2n}\Omega S^{2n+1}$ is the same as the Hopf invariant map is proved by Prop. 1.30 of Hatcher's spectral sequence book.